# Combination of liquid simulation and rigid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

Please forgive poor English by translation

Version used: 3.1.0 Alpha

When liquid collision and rigid body are used together
the fluid accelerates to an unusual degree.

Is there any way to calculate this correctly?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Self-resolved.

The value of the sampling substep in the liquid collision settings was too high.
By setting it to 1, the simulation became more natural, as shown in this image.

[image]

Comment: although you still have some liquid leaking through the bottom of the teapot

Comment: That's a separate issue from the one I mentioned, since it's a matter of liquid resolution and collision detection thickness. ; )